# SAS EG 5.1 - PROC SQL

Tags: autocomplete, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

How can I use autocomplete in proc SQL queries?

For example, when I use proc print I can use autocomplete for libnames, tables and fields.

How can I do the same in proc SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Enterprise Guide 5.1, you can autocomplete *table names* only in PROC SQL, as far as I can tell.  So:

```
proc sql;
  select * from sashelp.class
  where age > 13;
quit;
```

When you started typing `sashelp` it would not autocomplete for you, but when you start typing `.class` it will (assuming your SAS session is connected, and you wait a bit for it to search the metadata - in my uses I almost always have to type the `.`, then backspace over it, and type it again, for it to work properly).  You also couldn't autocomplete `age`.

In EG 7.1 (and not 6.1), you can also autocomplete the libname (`sashelp`).  The where clause however seems to still be not autocompleted.  PROC SQL syntax is a bit more complex for the autocomplete parser to parse, so it's probably left out for that reason.

---

As Raphael notes in comments, `ctrl+L` is the hotkey for Autocomplete Library; this works *anywhere* in an editor window (including in open code), so this would be a workaround for EG 5.1/6.1 not having this by default in `PROC SQL`.

However, the key combination for Data Set Variable is `ctrl+shift+V`, and this does *not* work in PROC SQL (but does work in Data Step, even in code that doesn't normally work this way).  My guess is that SQL is harder to parse which dataset a variable is from, and SAS hasn't worked out this functionality yet.

Comment: I understand. But when we press ctrl+L, SAS EG 5.1 shows us all the libs. Is there a shortcut to autocomplete tables and fields?

Autocomplete works for libs, tables and fields in proc print. So, I have imagined that it works in print too.

Comment: @RaphaelLima Unfortunately not; I expanded my answer some, but it sounds like variable autocompletion is not possible so far.  Library is, as you note, so that should help at least.